# CASE Statement to exclude specific values in SUM

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I was trying to get this query to sum customer charges without including the taxes. In this case, the customer charge and taxes are are called i.cht_itemcode(VARCHAR(5)), which is on the Invoicedetail table.
Originally i used a LEFT JOIN to bring in the Invoicedetail table, which was just wrong. The value from the  Orderheader table, o.ord_charge, is the same as ivd_charge where cht_itemcode is LHF.

I ended up writting that part this way instead, and removing the left join. Instead of trying to do the SUM in the query itself, i decided to split the 2 different charge amounts and do the SUM in SSRS instead.

```
CASE WHEN o.ord_invoicestatus='AVL' 
  THEN o.ord_charge 
ELSE (select sum(i.ivd_charge) from invoicedetail i 
       where i.cht_itemcode='LHF' and i.ord_hdrnumber=o.ord_hdrnumber)
END as 'Revenue',
(SELECT SUM(I.IVD_CHARGE) from invoicedetail i where 
i.ord_hdrnumber=o.ord_hdrnumber and i.cht_itemcode not in ('LHF','HST2','TAX3','GST','BCCT'))'Accessorial'
```

Comment: you can put a `CASE` in your `SUM` but not sure that's what you're asking.. `SUM(CASE WHEN cht_itemcode IN ('HST2','TAX3','BCCT') THEN 0 ELSE i.IVD_CHARGE END)`

Answer (score 0):

I would personally change the join to invoice detail to a subquery join instead

```
FROM  Orderheader o
left join (SELECT i.ord_hdrnumber,
                  SUM(i.IVD_CHARGE) IVD_CHARGE
            FROM invoicedetail i
            WHERE i.cht_itemcode<>'DEL' 
                    and cht_itemcode NOT IN ('HST2','TAX3','BCCT')
           GROUP BY i.ord_hdrnumber
        ) i ON o.ord_hdrnumber=i.ord_hdrnumber
```

then just change your case statement to

```
(CASE WHEN o.ord_invoicestatus='AVL'
     THEN o.ord_totalcharge ELSE i.IVD_CHARGE END) AS 'Revenue'
```

dont forget to remove `i.cht_itemcode` from your group by

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to follow all of your question, but I think you're on the right track with your Case/Sum statement; I'm a big fan of conditional SUM statements.  However I prefer to do it slightly differently.

You need to write your query so that all of the joins are performed for all of your data, then in your actual select field where you are performing the sum:

```
SUM( Case 
     When code_table.code_desc = 'Tax Code' 
     Then Null Else value_table.dollar_value END )
```

The difference is that the sum is at the beginning of the line rather than embedded in the case. What this allow you to do is use a `GROUP BY` at the end of your query to deal with splayed records that you want combined into one. Perhaps this helps you deal with the multiple records that you are getting back?

Comment: I think this method actually worked; I removed the left join altogether and decided to split the values in 2 columns. It looks like this now:CASE WHEN o.ord_invoicestatus='AVL' then o.ord_charge ELSE (select sum(i.ivd_charge) from invoicedetail i where i.cht_itemcode='LHF' and i.ord_hdrnumber=o.ord_hdrnumber) END as 'Revenue',
(SELECT SUM(I.IVD_CHARGE) from invoicedetail i where i.ord_hdrnumber=o.ord_hdrnumber and i.cht_itemcode not in ('LHF','HST2','TAX3','GST','BCCT'))'Accessorial'

Comment: Glad to hear that you're on the right track. I would just caution you to be wary of "windowed" statements. By embedding a full blown select statement in a field you dramatically increase the overhead of your query, and at times this can really decrease the performance of the query optimizer that's built into the engine. If you're developing this query on a limited development database, or if you're expecting the database you deploy this on to grow rapidly, make sure you test it with the worst imaginable scenario in terms of data.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up removing the LEFT JOIN altogether and having 2 separate columns, 1 for the customer charge and 1 for accessorials so now i can add them together in SSRS.

```
CASE WHEN o.ord_invoicestatus='AVL' then o.ord_charge ELSE 
     (select sum(i.ivd_charge) from invoicedetail i where 
      i.cht_itemcode='LHF' and i.ord_hdrnumber=o.ord_hdrnumber) END as 'Revenue',
(SELECT SUM(I.IVD_CHARGE) from invoicedetail i where 
i.ord_hdrnumber=o.ord_hdrnumber and i.cht_itemcode not in ('LHF','HST2','TAX3','GST','BCCT'))'Accessorial'
```